# Ubuntu TuxOnIce and uswsusp doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, tuxonice

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 installed on Dell Inspiron 1545, I've upgraded my kernell to 3.8.2 as well due to read only problems I was having with 3.5.0-25.

But now I can't get my hibernate to work. I've tried TuxOnIce and uswsusp.

uswsusp - seems to hibernate ok but on resume get stuck.

TuxOnIce - again seems to hibernate ok, all I get is flashing cursor and black screen then powers off. When I resume it seems to boot as if I've restarted the laptop, it doesn't bring up any previously opened programs and it seems to put my filesystem into read only state as well.

Can you please help me get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the TuxOnIce problem, but I solved the "hang on resume" problem by inserting into `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/uswsusp` at line 36 the following line:

`[ -x /bin/plymouth ] && plymouth quit`

According to [this comment on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uswsusp/+bug/816859/comments/9), plymouth needs to quit before resume can continue. Inserting the above line before `/sbin/resume` makes sure that happens.